# How do I resolve the `Procedure or function addQuestion has too many arguments specified.' error?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

When I run the following stored proc, I get:

`Procedure or function addQuestion has too many arguments specified.'

I believe the reason is because @qnum is in the INSERT statement but not declared as a parameter at the declaration part of the stored procedure.

Here is the stored proc below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[addQuestion](@surveyID INT, @question VARCHAR(255), @AnswerType CHAR(1), @CorrectAnswer NVARCHAR(50))
AS
DECLARE @qnum INT

SELECT @qnum = ISNULL(MIN(QuestionOrder),0)+1
FROM SurveyQuestions WHERE SurveyID = @surveyID

INSERT INTO SurveyQuestions(SurveyID, Question, AnswerType,CorrectAnswer,QuestionOrder)
VALUES (@SurveyID, @Question, @AnswerType,@CorrectAnswer,@qnum)
```

How do I resolve this?

I think that the key to fixing it has to do with fixing this bit first:

```
DECLARE @qnum INT

SELECT @qnum = ISNULL(MIN(QuestionOrder),0)+1
FROM SurveyQuestions WHERE SurveyID = @surveyID
```

Thanks much in advance

Comment: Can you post your call that executes this procedure? You're almost certainly passing too many parameters to it.

Comment: @AdrianWragg, It is working. I was passing one too many arguments in app.

If you could put your solution where I would credit you, that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error simply indicates that you are passing too many arguments when calling the stored procedure.

Double-check your call, and re-try.

Answer (score 0):

You may get the list of paramters with this script:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.parameters p
WHERE   p.object_id=OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[addQuestion]');
```

References: [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176074.aspx)
sys.parameters

> Contains a row for each parameter of an object that accepts
>   parameters. If the object is a scalar function, there is also a single
>   row describing the return value. That row will have a parameter_id
>   value of 0.

Comment: Thank you @Adrian and Bogdan,

I am dealing with a different issue that is preventing me from responding to your posts.

I will get back with you as soon as possible.

Thanks for your kindness.